# Elementary geometry question involving quadrilateral and bisector given with picture.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: geometry question]

> - $ABCD$ is a quadrilateral.
> - $m(\widehat{BAC})=48^\circ$.
> - $m(\widehat{CAD})=66^\circ$.
> - $m(\widehat{CBD})=m(\widehat{DBA})$.
> - What is $\color{magenta}{m(\widehat{BDC})=x}$?

Tried lots of things but all i can found is that all the angles, except given ones and $\color{magenta}x$, depends on the $m(\widehat{CBA})$. The answer is $\color{magenta}{24^\circ}$.

Comment: I agree; I think there are two degrees of freedom still. Are you sure there weren't other assumptions in the problem, like line $BD$ bisecting angle $D$ also, or $ABCD$ being a special type of quadrilateral?

Comment: @GregMartin, yes, above are the only given things. I checked that $x=24^\circ$ no matter what $\widehat{CBA}$ values; so the question has an unique solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Construction: Let the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ cut $BD$ at $X$. Then, Join $CX$.

$X$ is actually is the in-center of $\triangle ABC$. Thus, $p = q$

$r = t + q = \dfrac {2t + 2q }{2} = \dfrac {180 - 48}{2} = 66^ 0 = \angle CAD$

This means $XADC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral

Therefore, by angle in the same segment, $x = \angle CAX = \dfrac {48}{2} = 24^0$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the very last sentence?

Comment: @GregMartin If a quadrilateral is cyclic, the angles in the same segment should be equal. $\angle CAX$ and $x$ are instances of such. $\angle ADB$ and $p$ formed another equal pair. Remember also that AX is an angle bisector of $\angle BAC$